# Deploy iPad App - Enterprise or Developer Licence

Tags: ios, ipad, deployment

I'm sorry if this question has been asked. I have looked but can not find the question/answer.

I work for a web agency and am now developing IOS Apps for deployment on iPads.
We have the **Developer licence** from Apple however, reading the blurb it suggests that the Apps need to go through the App Store.
Due to the nature of the Apps (Medical) they can not be on the App Store.
Is this **Developer licence** using the "Ad Hoc" option enough to deploy the App to clients (not in our company) using a link, or do I need to use the **Enterprise Licence**?

The Enterprise Licence does say:

> **You plan to only distribute your iOS apps within your company or organization**
>
> The Enterprise Program is intended for developers who wish to develop
>   and distribute their iOS apps within their company or organisation.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I'm sorry this is a bit of a random/bitty question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Enterprise License is *only* for your company. If you need to distribute the app to members outside your own organization, it *has* to go through the AppStore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ad-hoc distribution is limited to 99 devices and the enterprise limitation is 2k or 5k, not sure. If you want to really distribute your app, but limit its usage, then you have to build an authorization mechanism into your app (like http://www.doccheck.com for doctors). You may use an existing service like this or you can implement your own.
Enterprise distribution, btw, requires the registration of the device in your company. I would not do that as a customer in that case, maybe that is an issue in your case, too.