# How can i sell an iPad app without passing from Apple Store

Tags: ipad, app-store

I am building an iPad app to be sold to specific customers [stores] for handling their activity.
I would like not to pass from App Store but install on their iPads. 
Is it possible? If yes, What kind of license/certificate has to be applied?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploy iPad App - Enterprise or Developer Licence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520098/deploy-ipad-app-enterprise-or-developer-licence)

Comment: You need to investigate the Apple B2B program and the Volume Purchasing Program.  This allows you to sell directly to to other businesses (not the general public) although it does require the app to be downloaded by your business customers from a closed section of the App Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are distributing iPad applications outside your own organization, either the iPads need to be jailbroken or the applications must go through the App Store. Apple does not offer any other option.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look into the [iOS Developer Enterprise Program.](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)

Comment: That is limited to distribution "within your company or organization". He wants to sell to customers.

Comment: That's true. That being said, he *could* charge his customers for app use, but I'm not sure of the legality of that.

Comment: I don't see anything that prohibits charging. The problem is that the customers are not within his organization.

Answer (score 0):

> In order to develop and install apps on iOS devices, developers must register with 
>   Apple and join the iOS Developer Program. The real-world identity of each developer, 
>   whether an individual or a business, is verified by Apple before their certificate is 
>   issued. This certificate enables developers to sign apps and submit them to the App 
>   Store for distribution. As a result, all apps in the App Store have been submitted by an 
>   identifiable person or organization, serving as a deterrent to the creation of malicious 
>   apps.  They have also been reviewed by Apple to ensure they operate as described 
>   and don’t contain obvious bugs or other problems. In addition to the technology 
>   already discussed, this curation process gives customers confidence in the quality of 
>   the apps they buy.
>
> Businesses also have the ability to write in-house apps for use within their organization 
>   and distribute them to their employees. Businesses and organizations can apply to 
>   the iOS Developer Enterprise Program (iDEP) with a D-U-N-S number. Apple approves 
>   applicants after verifying their identity and eligibility. Once an organization becomes a 
>   member of iDEP, it can register to obtain a provisioning profile that permits in-house 
>   apps to run on devices it authorizes. Users must have the provisioning profile installed 
>   in order to run the in-house apps. This ensures that only the organization’s intended 
>   users are able to load the apps onto their iOS devices.

From apple